# Show hidden textbox with Polymer after button press

Tags: javascript, css, polymer

I have the following code

```
<dom-module id="practice-list">
    <template>
        <paper-drawer-panel>
            <paper-header-panel main mode="waterfall-tall">
                <paper-toolbar id="mainToolbar">
                    <paper-icon-button id="paperToggle" icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
                    <span class="flex"></span>
                    <paper-icon-button icon="search" on-tap="srchandler" id="srchandler"></paper-icon-button>
                    <input type="text" id="searchText" show$="{{show}}" />
                    <div class="middle paper-font-display2 app-name ident">Practice List</div>
                </paper-toolbar>
            </paper-header-panel>
        </paper-drawer-panel>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "practice-list",
            show: {
                type: Boolean,
                value: false
            },
            ready: function () {
            },
            srchandler: function () {
                this.show = !this.show;
                alert('Is it showing?');
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Which in turn uses the following css

```
#searchText
{
    width:0px;
    border: none;
    line-height:30px;
    border-radius:5px;

    background:#3F59B5;
    color:#fff;

    outline: 0;

    visibility: hidden;

}

#searchText[show] input {
    padding: 10px;
    visibility: visible;
    width:200px;

}
```

Now I was trying to use the technique described here, but to no avail.

[polymer search input text from icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29463855/polymer-search-input-text-from-icon)

Even though I know the handler for the on-tap of the paper-icon-button is working and called the textbox does not appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the HTML5 attribute `hidden`? (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_hidden.asp) for more info)

Your input would change to:

```
<input type="text" id="searchText" hidden$="{{hidden}}" />
```

Then in your CSS you can remove the `visibility` rules and the `show` attribute:

```
#searchText {
    border: none;
    line-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #3F59B5;
    color: #fff;
    outline: 0;
}

#searchText input {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

And change the property `show` to be `hidden` to make the things a bit more logical:

```
hidden: {
    type: Boolean,
    value: true
},
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/mNiHuwyHGpW67JLyEfSs?p=preview) is a very simple plunker of this in action.

Comment: If you use this, you might want to rename your `show` property as it might get a bit confusing!

Comment: Tried that - but now it starts visible and then vanishes when you click the search button - I need it to do the opposite - start invisible and then show when the search button is pressed. I also had to remove the width:0px from the #searchText CSS to get it to show at all.

Comment: Too quick - got it now, but had to use Ben's suggestion and add this.showSearch = true; to the ready function.

Comment: Change the name of your property `show` to `hidden` to make the logic a bit easier to understand. Then change it's value to be `true` which will mean it is hidden by default. I've updated the plunker to make this a bit clearer.